# Using operating hours in Open Graph business object type

Tags: facebook-opengraph

How do I properly add markup for business hours that are part of the [Facebook Open Graph meta tags for the business object property](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/business.business)?

For example, how would I represent the following business hours: Mon-Fri: 9am-5pm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include **Mon-Fri: 9am-5pm** in the Open Graph meta tags you will need to mark up each day in its own group like so:

```
<meta property="business:hours:day" content="monday" />
<meta property="business:hours:start" content="09:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:end" content="17:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:day" content="tuesday" />
<meta property="business:hours:start" content="09:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:end" content="17:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:day" content="wednesday" />
<meta property="business:hours:start" content="09:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:end" content="17:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:day" content="thursday" />
<meta property="business:hours:start" content="09:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:end" content="17:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:day" content="friday" />
<meta property="business:hours:start" content="09:00" />
<meta property="business:hours:end" content="17:00" />
```

The property tags for hours (`business:hours:start` and `business:hours:end`) can be written in any of the following formats:

Examples for 1 PM

- 13:00 (24-hour notation)
- 1:00 PM (12-hour clock with period in uppercase)
- 1:00 pm (12-hour clock with period in lowercase)

A single day must consist of at least the three fields:

- `business:hours:day`
- `business:hours:start`
- `business:hours:end`

Comment: Oh I see, so the order of the meta data tags is what determines which day they belong to. Because otherwise it looks like we are re-declaring the same `business:hours:start` data.